In spring cloud gateway, is it possible to make a filter that redirects to a route based on data read from the json request body?
In spring cloud gateway, i have these two routes configured in the yaml file:
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: springcloud
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/springcloud/**
          filters:
            - name: InterceptRouteGatewayFilter



        - id: springcloud2
          uri: http://localhost:8082/
          predicates:
          - Path=/springcloud/**
          filters:
          - name: InterceptRouteGatewayFilter

these routes contain two POST rest services with the same uri:
http://localhost:8081/springcloud/microservice
http://localhost:8082/springcloud/microservice
I need to call the right one based on data read from the json request body. Let's say that if it returns 1, it calls the first uri, otherwise the second. How do i achieve this? Is this the right way, or would this logic make more sense as a custom predicate? Here is my code example
@Component
public class InterceptRouteGatewayFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<Object> {

    

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            Flux<DataBuffer> body = request.getBody();

            return body.collectList().flatMap(dataBuffers -> {
                byte[] contentBytes = dataBuffers.stream()
                        .map(buffer -> {
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableByteCount()];
                            buffer.read(bytes);
                            return bytes;
                        })
                        .reduce(new byte[0], (a, b) -> {
                            byte[] result = new byte[a.length + b.length];
                            System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
                            System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
                            return result;
                        });

                String bodyJson = new String(contentBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                String result= extractCodiceRicevitoria(bodyJson);
           
                

                    if (result.equals("1") {
                        // CALL http://localhost:8081/springcloud/microservice
                        
                    } else { //CALL http://localhost:8082/springcloud/microservice }
                
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            });
        };
    }

    private String extractCodiceRicevitoria(String requestBody) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(requestBody).getAsJsonObject();
        return jsonObject.get("codiceRicevitoria").getAsString();
    }
}

